# bootstrap navbar-collapse is changing direction of navigation items

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header navbar-right">
    <span class="hidden-lg hidden-md" style="padding:8px; color:gray; font-size:20px;">
     תפריט
    </span>
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
      data-target="#toggle" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
    </div>
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="toggle">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li><a href="cart.php">עגלת קניות <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
         <span class="badge badge-error">0</span>
               </a></li>
       <li><a href="journalism.php">קטעי עיתונות</a></li>
       <li><a href="qna.php">שאלות נפוצות</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">ערכות מומלצות<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li class='text-right'><a href='kits.php?id=1'>עור רפווי וקמטים</a></li>
             <li role='separator' class='divider' style='background-color:darkgray;'></li><li class='text-right'><a href='kits.php?id=2'>היפר פיגמנטציה וכתמי עור</a></li>
             <li role='separator' class='divider' style='background-color:darkgray;'></li><li class='text-right'><a href='kits.php?id=3'>עור יבש וחסר לחות</a></li>
             <li role='separator' class='divider' style='background-color:darkgray;'></li><li class='text-right'><a href='kits.php?id=4'>עור עייף וחסר חיוניות וזוהר</a></li>
             <li role='separator' class='divider' style='background-color:darkgray;'></li><li class='text-right'><a href='kits.php?id=5'>עור רגיש ואדמומי</a></li>
             <li role='separator' class='divider' style='background-color:darkgray;'></li><li class='text-right'><a href='kits.php?id=6'>מצבי עור מיוחדים: אקזמה עור מגורה סימניה מתיחה חשיפה לשמש ועוד</a></li>
             <li role='separator' class='divider' style='background-color:darkgray;'></li><li class='text-right'><a href='kits.php?id=7'>עור שמן\מעורב התפרצויות של פצעונים\אקנה</a></li>
             <li role='separator' class='divider' style='background-color:darkgray;'></li>        </ul>
        <li><a href="thestorybehind.php">הסיפור שמאוחרי המותג</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
         <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">מוצרים<span class="caret"></span></a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li class='text-right'><a href='product.php?id=1'>שמן מרוכז רב תכליתי לפנים ולגוף</a></li>
             <li role='separator' class='divider' style='background-color:darkgray;'></li><li class='text-right'><a href='product.php?id=2'>קרם ג’ל עם אפקט מתיחה מיידי</a></li>
             <li role='separator' class='divider' style='background-color:darkgray;'></li><li class='text-right'><a href='product.php?id=3'>ג'ל ניקוי מטהר ומרענן לניקוי העור</a></li>
             <li role='separator' class='divider' style='background-color:darkgray;'></li><li class='text-right'><a href='product.php?id=4'>מי פנים מרעננים להרגעת ולטיהור העור</a></li>
             <li role='separator' class='divider' style='background-color:darkgray;'></li><li class='text-right'><a href='product.php?id=5'>סרום ליפט למיצוק העור ולתוספת לחות</a></li>
             <li role='separator' class='divider' style='background-color:darkgray;'></li><li class='text-right'><a href='product.php?id=6'>קרם פנים משקם רב תכליתי(Regenerating)</a></li>
             <li role='separator' class='divider' style='background-color:darkgray;'></li><li class='text-right'><a href='product.php?id=7'>קרם רב תכליתי למיצוק ולמתיחת העור באופן טבעי(Anti-Aging)</a></li>
             <li role='separator' class='divider' style='background-color:darkgray;'></li><li class='text-right'><a href='product.php?id=8'>קרם עיניים למראה צעיר ורענן</a></li>
             <li role='separator' class='divider' style='background-color:darkgray;'></li>         </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="index.php">ראשי</a></li>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header navbar-right">
            <span class="hidden-lg hidden-md" style="padding:8px; color:gray; font-size:20px;">
                תפריט
            </span>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#toggle" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="toggle">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="cart.php">עגלת קניות <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
                            <?php if(isset($_SESSION['cart']) && $_SESSION['cart'] ): ?> <span class="badge badge-right"><?php echo count($_SESSION['cart']) ?></span> 
                            <?php else: ?> <span class="badge badge-error">0</span>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </a></li>
                        <li><a href="journalism.php">קטעי עיתונות</a></li>
                        <li><a href="qna.php">שאלות נפוצות</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">ערכות מומלצות<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <?php 
                                    $kits = get_kits();
                                    if($kits)
                                        foreach($kits as $kit)
                                            echo "<li class='text-right'><a href='kits.php?id=".$kit->get_id()."'>".$kit->get_name()."</a></li>
                                                <li role='separator' class='divider' style='background-color:darkgray;'></li>";
                                ?>
                            </ul>
                            <li><a href="thestorybehind.php">הסיפור שמאוחרי המותג</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">מוצרים<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <?php 
                                        $products = get_products();
                                        foreach($products as $prod)
                                            echo "<li class='text-right'><a href='product.php?id=".$prod->get_id()."'>".$prod->get_name()."</a></li>
                                                <li role='separator' class='divider' style='background-color:darkgray;'></li>";
                                    ?>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="index.php">ראשי</a></li>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have this code (HTML5 with Bootstrap and PHP) and I'm having some issues when this navbar is showing on mobile.
when you look at this on mobile you can see that the links are in the wrong place. For example:

> link 1 | link 2 | link 3

On mobile it will show like this:

> link 3
>   link 2
>   link 1

Instead of:

> link 1
>   link 2
>   link 3

So my "main" link will be last and my last link will be first and that is not what I want.

Comment: please add code snippet with static html along with all source files, not php code

Comment: Ok I added snippet I hope it will help to understand

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: both screens small and large showing same direction of navigation li, see attachment: https://imgur.com/a/gzcW4, navigation item with counter "0" is first item and its item appearance is first on both screens.

Comment: the thing is you guys dont understand the idea behind what Im saying..
this is hebrew and it suppose to be RTL so the link from the right suppose to be the first link so on... and on the mobile it show them other way around

Comment: @Talg3017, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to use only one  element for your element? I don't see a reason for adding two divs that have same function.

And I'm assuming that error is related to your CSS file 'cause your bootstrap structure is OK. Maybe if you are using RTL direction or something similar?

---

Here is the solution. Don't reverse your list order, make standard layout like this and to your css code make links float: right instead float: left;

CSS

```
.navbar-nav>li {
    float: right;
}
```

HTML

```
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="toggle">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="index.php">ראשי</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">מוצרים<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class='text-right'><a href='product.php?id=1'>שמן מרוכז רב תכליתי לפנים ולגוף</a></li>
                    <li role='separator' class='divider' style='background-color:darkgray;'></li><li class='text-right'><a href='product.php?id=2'>קרם ג’ל עם אפקט מתיחה מיידי</a></li>
                    <li role='separator' class='divider' style='background-color:darkgray;'></li><li class='text-right'><a href='product.php?id=3'>ג'ל ניקוי מטהר ומרענן לניקוי העור</a></li>
                    <li role='separator' class='divider' style='background-color:darkgray;'></li><li class='text-right'><a href='product.php?id=4'>מי פנים מרעננים להרגעת ולטיהור העור</a></li>
                    <li role='separator' class='divider' style='background-color:darkgray;'></li><li class='text-right'><a href='product.php?id=5'>סרום ליפט למיצוק העור ולתוספת לחות</a></li>
                    <li role='separator' class='divider' style='background-color:darkgray;'></li><li class='text-right'><a href='product.php?id=6'>קרם פנים משקם רב תכליתי(Regenerating)</a></li>
                    <li role='separator' class='divider' style='background-color:darkgray;'></li><li class='text-right'><a href='product.php?id=7'>קרם רב תכליתי למיצוק ולמתיחת העור באופן טבעי(Anti-Aging)</a></li>
                    <li role='separator' class='divider' style='background-color:darkgray;'></li><li class='text-right'><a href='product.php?id=8'>קרם עיניים למראה צעיר ורענן</a></li>
                    <li role='separator' class='divider' style='background-color:darkgray;'></li>                                   </ul>
          </li>
                    </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">ערכות מומלצות<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class='text-right'><a href='kits.php?id=1'>עור רפווי וקמטים</a></li>
                                            <li role='separator' class='divider' style='background-color:darkgray;'></li><li class='text-right'><a href='kits.php?id=2'>היפר פיגמנטציה וכתמי עור</a></li>
                                            <li role='separator' class='divider' style='background-color:darkgray;'></li><li class='text-right'><a href='kits.php?id=3'>עור יבש וחסר לחות</a></li>
                                            <li role='separator' class='divider' style='background-color:darkgray;'></li><li class='text-right'><a href='kits.php?id=4'>עור עייף וחסר חיוניות וזוהר</a></li>
                                            <li role='separator' class='divider' style='background-color:darkgray;'></li><li class='text-right'><a href='kits.php?id=5'>עור רגיש ואדמומי</a></li>
                                            <li role='separator' class='divider' style='background-color:darkgray;'></li><li class='text-right'><a href='kits.php?id=6'>מצבי עור מיוחדים: אקזמה עור מגורה סימניה מתיחה חשיפה לשמש ועוד</a></li>
                                            <li role='separator' class='divider' style='background-color:darkgray;'></li><li class='text-right'><a href='kits.php?id=7'>עור שמן\מעורב התפרצויות של פצעונים\אקנה</a></li>
                                            <li role='separator' class='divider' style='background-color:darkgray;'></li>                               </ul>
                        <li><a href="thestorybehind.php">הסיפור שמאוחרי המותג</a></li>
          <li><a href="qna.php">שאלות נפוצות</a></li>
          <li><a href="journalism.php">קטעי עיתונות</a></li>
          <li><a href="cart.php">עגלת קניות <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
                             <span class="badge badge-error">0</span>
                          </a>
        </li>
                </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: I so use rtl becouse its hebrew it suppose to go to be rtl..
and that my issue cos the "main" link is last when it suppose to be first on mobiles.

Comment: when I tried your solution the links were 1 beside eachother and not 1 after another..

Comment: I'll post you a couple of screenshots, maybe you can spot what is different in your code. I'm assuming you don't have display:block; on a tag.
http://prntscr.com/hnkat2
http://prntscr.com/hnkbkf

http://prntscr.com/hnkc0f

Comment: ye I need to add display: block; on a tag.

Comment: One more solution would be to add something like this to your code:
`@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
    .navbar-nav>li {
    width: 100%;
  }
}`

or 

`@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
    .navbar-nav>li {
   float: none
  }
}`

Comment: where did you add the "display: block" to? I cant seem to make it work.

Comment: Use one of two snippets I posted on comment before. Your layout is changing on smaller resolution so snippets will do the fix on mobile layout. 

Here is once more final code for your website:

`      
.navbar-nav>li {
        float: right;
      }

      @media screen and (max-width:767px) {
        .navbar-nav>li {
          width: 100%;
          float: none;
        }
      }
`

Comment: Thnx alot, Im very very thnxful! have a great weekend ^_^

Answer (score 1):

I copied the same code you have written here, the first one (devoid of any PHP) and ran it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ao2ezxjt/).

It works fine for me, all the links are in the same order.

```
 - Ignore this line -
```

You can change the screen size in the fiddle link to see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

See result of my snippet, direction changed on small devices only using css. I have used only three items with changed sequence of navigation items, you can use all but in same sequence which I have used.

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
        .navbar-nav>li {
            float: left;
            display:inline-block;
            width:100%;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .navbar-nav>li {
            float:right !important;
        }
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header navbar-right">
            <span class="hidden-lg hidden-md" style="padding:8px; color:gray; font-size:20px;">
                תפריט
            </span>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#toggle" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="toggle">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="qna.php">שאלות נפוצות</a></li>
                <li><a href="journalism.php">קטעי עיתונות</a></li>
                <li><a href="cart.php">עגלת קניות <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span><span class="badge badge-error">0</span>
                    </a></li>

            </ul>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```